# Question about subspaces of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

From Rotman's Introduction to Algebraic Topology:

> If $A$ is the affine set in $R^n$ spanned by an affine independent set
>   $\{ p_0, ..., p_m\}$, then $A$ is a translate of an $m$-dimensional sub-vector-space V of $R^n$, namely
>   $A = V + x_0$ for some $x_0 \in R^n$.
>
> PROOF: Let $V$ be the sub-vector-space with basis $\{p_1-p_0, ..., p_m-p_0\}$ and set $x_0=p_0$.

What exactly is the sub-vector-space a subspace of?

Because for

$A =\{\sum_{i=0}^{m} t_i p_i : \sum t_i = 1\} = V + p_0 = \{v + p_0 : v \in V\} = \{ \sum_{i=1}^{m} j_i(p_i-p_0) + p_0\}$

wouldn't we have to have a similar summation restriction on the coefficients?

Comment: It is, of course, a subspace of $R^n$.  I don't know what you mean by "Because for" etc. where did you get the condition that the "$t_i" must sum to 1?  That would not be true for an affine space or a vector space.

Comment: @user247327 The $\sum t_i = 1$ condition comes from the fact that an affine set spanned by an affine independent set $\{p_0,..,p_m\}$ equals the set of all affine combinations of the points $\{p_0,...,p_m\}$, and affine combinations of points are sums of the form $\sum t_i p_i$ such that $\sum t_i = 1$.  If $A$ is constricted by that summation and $A = V + p_0$, then shouldn't $V+p_0$ be subject to the same constraints?

Comment: @user247327 What I don't understand is why these two sets are equal but the first is constrained and the second one isn't.  As in $A$ is all affine combinations and the second set is all linear combinations where there's more linear combinations than affine combinations.

Comment: "why these two sets are equal but the first is constrained and the second one isn't."

Comment: "why these two sets are equal but the first is constrained and the second one isn't."  The point is that the first set **with the constraint** is equal to the second set.  If we did not have the constraint, then the first set would contain the second but be larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider first a special case with only two points $p_0$ and $p_1$. The [affine hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_hull) $A$ of those is the set of all affine combinations
$$
A=\{t_0p_0+t_1p_1\colon\ t_0+t_1=1\}.
$$

[image]

The condition $t_0+t_1=1$ means that we can choose $t_1$ as we like, it is a free variable, and then take $t_0=1-t_1$. Let's set this $t_0$ into the expression
$$
t_0p_0+t_1p_1=(1-t_1)p_0+t_1p_1=p_0+t_1(p_1-p_0).
$$
We see now that the set $A$ can be represented as a given translation by the vector $p_0$ plus the free movement along the vector $p_1-p_0$. Note that there is no restriction on $t_1$, it is a free variable.

In general, we do the same: since $\sum_{i=0}^nt_i=1$ we can write
$$
\sum_{i=0}^nt_ip_i=\sum_{i=0}^nt_ip_i-\underbrace{\sum_{i=0}^nt_i}_{=1}p_0+p_0=\sum_{i=0}^nt_i(p_i-p_0)+p_0=\sum_{i=1}^nt_i(p_i-p_0)+p_0.
$$
The variables $t_1,\ldots,t_n$ can be chosen freely, and the only dependent $t_0$ vanishes as $t_0(p_0-p_0)=0$. That's why we do not have any restrictions on the linear combinations of $p_i-p_0$, $i=1,\ldots,n$.